# Lightswitch on Server 2016

Tags: odata, visual-studio-lightswitch, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to get Lightswitch (From Visual Studio 2016) working on Server 2016.

The process of using WPI didn't work out very well, but it showed me the errors in IIS of which modules it couldn't install, and doing it manually worked through it, lightswitch was able to deploy and the basic UI comes up.

However, the OData Endpoints return a 404 error. Turning on tracing doesn't give anything informative (unlike [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lightswitch/2011/09/20/diagnosing-problems-in-a-deployed-3-tier-lightswitch-application-eric-erhardt/) I didn't get any nice big error messages) - it just shows the details of the request.

So how can I further investigate the issue, or even better, has anyone gotten it working on Server 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like I just had to ask. I had to add the Management OData IIS Extension ([handy link](https://winadminsblog.wordpress.com/category/2-features/management-odata-iis-extension/) for instructions) and now it works.